# Outer Join on list of Objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following objects:

```
class A {
   int id;
   String propA;
}

class B {
   int id;
   String propB;
}

class C {
   int id;
   String propA;
   String propB;
}
```

Given Lists of Objects A and B, I would like to compute a List of Objects C, which will be an object created from joining Object A with B by id; However, if the id is present in the list of objects A and not B or B and not A, I would like to include it in a list of objects C, but with missing property. In other words, doing join on following lists:

```
List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
listA.add(new A(1, "example1"));
listA.add(new A(2, "example2"));

List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
listB.add(new B(2, "another example2"));
listB.add(new B(3, "another example3"));
```

Should be equivalent to creating the following list:

```
List<C> listC = new ArrayList<>();
listC.add(new C(1, "example1", null));
listC.add(new C(2, "example2", "another example2"));
listC.add(new C(3, null, "another example3"));
```

I have seen similar issues solved with Stream API, but it was always a one-sided Outer Join; either way, I tried to adapt it to my needs.

My attempt is following:

```
//creating maps of ids to list elements, so I can access it from the final stream easily
Map<Integer, A> listAbyId = listA.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getId, Function.identity()));
Map<Integer, B> listBbyId = listB.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(B::getId, Function.identity()));

//creating set of all ids that are in both lists
Set<Integer> set = listA.stream().map(a -> a.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Integer> set2 = listB.stream().map(b -> b.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
HashSet<Integer> setc = new HashSet<>();
setc.addAll(set);
setc.addAll(set2);

//final stream that creates list of C objects.
List<C> listC = setc.stream().map(c -> new C(c,
                                            listAbyId.get(c) == null ? null : listAbyId.get(c).getPropA(),
                                            listBbyId.get(c) == null ? null : listBbyId.get(c).getPropB()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It works as intended, but it kind of seems like overkill. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Map<Integer, A> map = listA.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getId, item -> new C(item.getId(), item.getPropA(), null)));
listB.stream().forEach(item -> map.containsKey(item.getId()) ? map.get(item.getId()).setPropB(item.getPropB()) : map.put(item.getId(), item);
```

And then convert to list.

Comment: This is also interesting, however:
1. You are creating map <Integer, A>, but fill it with <Integer, C>;
2. As far as I know, you need to put Consumer into forEach, so the return type of your tertiary operator should be void, and Map.put(K key, V value) returns the value that was inserted into the map, but I was able to go around it by inserting a block with regular if-else expression.

Thank you though! :-)

Comment: Oh, and also, you are trying to insert object of type B into that map, when you work on stream created from listB - there should be some newly created object of type C instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your start is pretty good allready but you are right the MapOfA/B is a bit overkill

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add(new A(1, "texta"));
    listA.add(new A(2, "textA"));

    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    listB.add(new B(2, "textb"));
    listB.add(new B(3, "textB"));
    
    Set<Integer> ids = listA.stream().map(a -> a.id).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    listB.forEach(b -> ids.add(b.id));
    List<C> listC = ids.stream()
            .map(id -> new C(id, listA.stream().filter(a -> a.id == id).findAny().orElse(new A(0, null)).propA,
                    listB.stream().filter(b -> b.id == id).findAny().orElse(new B(0, null)).propB))
            .toList();

    }
```

Edit: I went to bed yesterday a bit frustrade. I could not figure out how to make it^^ simpler because I still overkill the question a tiny bit ...

So I improved it :D

```
List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
listA.add(new A(1, "texta"));
listA.add(new A(2, "textA"));

List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
listB.add(new B(2, "textb"));
listB.add(new B(3, "textB"));

List<C> listC = Stream.of(listA, listB).flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ab -> (ab instanceof A a) ? a.id : ((B) ab).id, ab -> {
            C c = new C();
            if (ab instanceof A a) {
                c.textA = a.text;
            } else {
                c.textB = ((B) ab).text;
            }
            return c;
        }, (c, newc) -> {
            if (c.textA == null) {
                c.textA = newc.textA;
            } else {
                c.textB = newc.textB;
            }
            return c;
        })).entrySet().stream().map(e -> {
            C c = e.getValue();
            c.id = e.getKey();
            return c;
        }).toList();
```

I created a `Stream.of` `lista` and `listb` which gave me `[lista, listb]`.

To extract the elemtents of `lista` and `listb` I used `flatMap(List::stream)` which turn the stream into `[lista[0], lista[1], listb[0], listb[1]]`.

From their I used `collector(Collectors.toMap(keyFunction, valueFunction, mergeFunction))` to collect the id as key and an instance of C as value.

With `ab instanceof A a` I could deside whether its an `instanceof` A or B and also auto cast ab to A and store it in a.

Now I had a `Map<Interger, C>` where the id was not stored inside C but as key. To map the key as C.id I iterate over the map using `.entrySet().stream()` and did just that ;)

Note that you need to replace `.toList()` with `.collect(Collectors.toList)` for Java versions lower 16.

Comment: It's not bad, definitely better than mine, though my IDE screams that Stream<C> doesn't have toList() method. If you use `.collect(Collectors.toList());`  however, it works perfectly.

Comment: I guess I just have a higher java version :D my SonarLint said I sould use `.toList()` instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: oh, you are right. I needed an older one. Mea culpa :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream#concat` and then `toMap` collector like below:

In case of duplicate id merge two objects(c,c2).

```
 Stream.concat(
                    listA.stream().map(a -> new C(a.id, a.getPropA(), null)),
                    listB.stream().map(b -> new C(b.id, null, b.getPropB()))
              )
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, Function.identity(), 
               (c, c2) -> {
                  c.setPropB(c2.getPropB());
                  return c;
         })).values();
```